# How to account for spatial autocorrelation when the outcome (distance cycled) is continuous?

Tags: gamma-distribution, continuous-data, spatial-correlation, inla

I aim to predict distance cycled based on population density, recreational area density, infrastructure density, road intersection density, and average gradient (hilliness). The response variable, distance cycled (km cycled per year), is continuous and strongly skewed to the right (see histogram below). Therefore, I was considering using a Gamma regression model.

[image]

However, the data is areal (aggregated for small areas within a region), so I also need to account for spatial autocorrelation. Is there any 'spatial Gamma regression model' for continuous response variables (strongly skewed to the right)?

I have looked at the Besag-York-Mollié (BYM) model (popular in disease mapping) included in the R-INLA R package, but I am not sure whether it would be suitable for my continuous outcome distance cycled.

Thanks!

---

I assumed I had to account for spatial autocorrelation after conducting a Moran's I test in my model using testSpatialAutocorrelation() in the R DHARMa package. For this, I used the following code:

```
m_glm = glmmTMB(km_c_l ~ Density_s + Recreational_a_s + Infrastructure_a_s + Connectivity_a_s + Gradient_s, family = Gamma(link = log), data = simd_gc2)

res_null = simulateResiduals(m_glm)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res_null, x = simd_gc2$lon, y = simd_gc2$lat)
```

These are the results:

```
DHARMa Moran's I test for distance-based autocorrelation

data:  res_null
observed = 0.0847314, expected = -0.0013423, sd = 0.0022684,
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: Distance-based autocorrelation
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV, Eugeni. Being "continuous" -- in whatever sense that might mean (continuity is a property of a model or a type of measurement, among other things, but is not an inherent property of data) -- ordinarily gives us little guidance concerning what an appropriate model might be.  Please describe your data in more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not to challenge any assumptions, but are you sure you need explicitly to account for spatial correlation?  Often, after including covariates (like geography, etc.) that *themselves* might exhibit such correlation, you will find the residuals either have no correlation or not enough to bother about, allowing you to apply standard models (and software) without the attendant spatial complications. // The distances cycled look strange: extremely few people cycle 90,000 km in a year, suggesting these distances are *sums* -- but that makes them depend strongly on population.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, whuber. Good point! Well, I tested for spatial autocorrelation using testSpatialAutocorrelation() in the DHARMa package. I will add the code and outcome of the test above (I do not know how to add it here).

Comment: Regarding distances cycled, yes they are sums of distances cycled per year per small area. I have 750 small areas in the region. They are calculated by multiplying the distance of street segments by Strava trip counts (at the street segment level). Differences among areas are huge and some look outliers, but nothing suggests these outliers are human errors.

Comment: I suppose with my Moran’s test shown above I am not considering your point, whuber. How can I test whether the ‘inclusion of covariates that *themselves* might exhibit such correlation’ makes the residuals either have no correlation or not enough to bother about?

Comment: You regress everything on the covariates and study the residuals from a spatial perspective.

Comment: This is what I've done with the DARMa package above, right?

Comment: Hi @whuber, could you please clarify what you mean by 'regress everything on the covariates'? Isn't this what I've done with the DARMa package (shown above)? Sorry, I have no stats background and I am still stuck with the problem. Do you think (if I find spatial autocorrelation in the residuals) the BYM model (with family = Gamma) is a good solution for my analysis?

Comment: I didn't read the code, but relied on the text of your question.  Yes, the code works with the residuals.  I'm not sure how meaningful any of that is, because I suspect that by *summing* distances cycled you're really just analyzing a proxy for the *population distribution* -- and of course that exhibits strong spatial correlation in area that is not entirely rural.

Comment: Yes, but I control for population density. Should I perhaps use a denominator in my dependent variable (distance cycled) such as area, infrastructure length, or population?

Comment: All my areas are urban -- They belong to a specific city.

Comment: How exactly do you "control for" population density?  Merely including it as an (additive) covariate in the model might be less effective than formulating a more meaningful way of measuring cycling, such as miles cycled per (adult?) resident per year.  BTW, I phrased my previous comment carefully: a "specific city" is certainly *not* "entirely rural"!

Comment: I "control for" population density including it (as an additive covariate) in the model. I know the distance cycled per year and area, and the population density per area. However, I do not know the distance cycled by the residents of each area --- this could be made by residents of other areas or cities. In any case, do you think the Besag-York-Mollié (BYM) model (using family = Gamma) included in the R-INLA R package is the right model to account for spatial autocorrelation with my current dependent variable (km cycled per year per area)?